# Какую выбрать библиотеку по работе с gui на java?

Tags: java, gui

Возникла идея написать простенькую программу для отображения взаимодействия трех "точек" на экране (Визуализация имитации гравитационного взаимодействия трех тел) с рисуемой, за точками линией.

Существует множество версий и мнений какая лучше и удобнее. Но меня интересует функционал связанный с совсем примитивными действиями, которые описал выше.

Comment: Моё лично мнение - не использовать Java для GUI вообще ) Но если бы мне было нужно именно на Java, я бы выбирал между Swing и JavaFX

Comment: @Russtam спасибо за совет, уже начал осваивать JavaFX из-за его некой схожести с знакомой мне Android. Была мысль попробовать Unity+C#, подозреваю что там будет это еще проще)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну это просто! Для всякой там гравитации и физики используем [jBox2d](https://github.com/jbox2d/jbox2d).
Для GUI используем [JavaFX](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/part1/).
А вот [тут](https://blogs.oracle.com/wayneyoung/entry/javafx_2_0_and_box2d) для этой комбинации отличный пример.

Ну и немного о [3D в JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm).

Comment: да, интересный пример, судя по всему jBox2d подойдет. Правда не могу найти человеческой документации

Comment: Попробуйте вот этот сайт http://www.jbox2d.org/, довольно много информации по jBox2d. Вики и примеры.

Comment: На самом деле, самый простой способ освоить jBox2D - это взять один пример и просто его рассмотреть поподробнее. Кратко: есть визуальная и "физическая" составляющая приложения. Визуальная составляющая связывается с физической. В физической прописываются силы, размеры объектов и их форма, определяются границы "мира", где эти силы и объекты будут действовать. А дальше запускается процесс "жизни" описанного "мира" и силы начинают влиять на объекты, двигая их.